# メソッドの書き方についての質問

Tags: ruby

いまtwitterのようなサイトを作っています。

他の人のコードを参考にしていると、`show` メソッドの所に

```
@tweets = @user.tweets.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
```

というコードがありました。

`tweets.paginate(page: params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')` のように機能させたいコードを何個でも `.xxx.yyy` のように連続して書けるのですか？そして１つずつ機能をもつコードを独立させて書かないで、連続させて書くメリットとは何ですか？

Comment: ドットで繋ぐのは、railsは関係なくメソッドチェーンと呼ばれる比較的よく使われるプログラム技法のひとつです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby では

```
str = " abc "
str2 = str.strip #=> "abc"
str2.length #=> 3
```

これを

```
"abc".trim.length #=> 3
```

と書くことが出来ます。`"abc".strip`の戻り値は`String`なので、`String`の`#length`メソッドを続けて書くことが出来ます。

冗長な括弧を付けると

```
("abc".trim).length
```

になります。

このようにメソッドをつなげて書く手法はメソッドチェインと呼ばれます。これができるかどうかは言語仕様次第です。

どのようなメソッドが書けるかは、一つ前のメソッドの戻り値次第です。

上記の例だと

```
" abc ".length.strip
```

とメソッドを逆にすると`NoMethodError`になります。`" abc ".length` の戻り値は`Fixnum`(数値)で、`Fixnum`には`#strip`というメソッドはないからです